# How can I run grunt with global path?

Tags: spring, gruntjs, grunt-usemin

When I run 'grunt' at commend line, error occurred 'enable to find local grunt.'
Because, in my directory there is no grunt module. I want to run grunt with global path and not contain node_modules in my project folder. The more adding node_modules in my project the slower running a project. 
In my project, there is only Gruntfile.js except for any other node_modules. 
How can I run grunt and grunt sub modules with global path?
I can't find solution about this problem anywhere.

Comment: You can't find a solution because that is not the recommended use of Grunt. It is an anti-pattern and considered bad practice. You can read about [installing global node modules on the npm blog](http://blog.nodejs.org/2011/03/23/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation), but again, it is not recommended.

Comment: @jakerella thanks to comment for me. But containing node modules in my project make my git project have too much file size. I don't know when I use spring project

Comment: You do not need to commit the `node_modules` directory to git, simply commit your `package.json` file which contains references to the module dependencies. Then, when you clone the project later (or when someone else clones it) simply run `npm install` and all dependencies will be downloaded again.