# Running grunt globally

Tags: gruntjs

I am new to Grunt and I must install it for a project,

I did follow the steps from this link http://gruntjs.com/getting-started#installing-the-cli

I did install the grunt-Cli globally and then create a folder in the root of the website on the D drive after that did create a simple hello world gruntfile.js and when I run the grunt from the project folder or any sub folder it works and no problem.

Now I would like to know how can we run the grunt from anywhere and not just from the project folder.

is this possible? or each time we must install the grunt for each project?

I ask this because we have IIS webserver and as you know there is prblem with 256 characters limit

Comment: The recommended way is to install grunt for each project. A similar question has been asked in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28272155/how-can-i-run-grunt-with-global-path?rq=1)

Comment: Thank you Rob for your comment, I know it is not recomaanded, but is it possible or not?